# document.getElementById().value empty

Tags: javascript

I generate the field 'endpoint' by combiningtwo field : 'version' and 'productName' but it's considerate like empty and I don't know why.

```js
function generateEndpoint() {
  var yourSelect = document.getElementById("version");
  document.getElementById('endpoint').value = '/' +
    document.getElementById('productName').value + '/' +
    yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value;

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.productName, 'has-success': valid.productName}">
  <label for="productName">product name *</label>
  <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" class="form-control" placeholder="example: myapi_fr_product " ng-model="api.productName" ng-required="true" onkeyup="generateEnpoint()">
  <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.productName.required">product name is required.</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.version, 'has-success': valid.version}">
  <label for="version">version *</label>
  <select name="version" id="version" class="form-control" ng-init="api.version = api.version || ''" ng-model="api.version" ng-required="true" onchange="generateEndpoint()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="beta">beta</option>
    <option value="v1">v1</option>
  </select>
  <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.version.required">version is required.</span> 
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.endpoint, 'has-success': valid.endpoint}">
  <label for="endpoint">exposure endpoint base path *</label>
  <input type="text" id="endpoint" name="endpoint" class="form-control" placeholder="example: /myapi/v1" ng-model="api.endpoint" ng-required="true">
  <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.endpoint.required">exposure endpoint is required.</span>
</div>
```

How can I solve my problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Changing the select reads the value of the first input successfully. Changing the first input suffers from an entirely different problem (which is obvious if you look at the error messages).

Comment: If you select the dropdown then value of Product Name + Version will add?.

Comment: The code works as expected, however, when using Angular.JS, you should not access the DOM directly. See this example for a AngularJS  select.

Comment: What example???

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `onkeyup="generateEndpoint()"` by `onkeypress="generateEndpoint()"`

```js
function generateEndpoint() {
  var yourSelect = document.getElementById("version");
  document.getElementById('endpoint').value = '/' +
    document.getElementById('productName').value + '/' +
    yourSelect.options[yourSelect.selectedIndex].value;

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.productName, 'has-success': valid.productName}">
  <label for="productName">product name *</label>
  <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" class="form-control" placeholder="example: myapi_fr_product " ng-model="api.productName" ng-required="true" onkeypress="generateEndpoint()">
  <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.productName.required">product name is required.</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.version, 'has-success': valid.version}">
  <label for="version">version *</label>
  <select name="version" id="version" class="form-control" ng-init="api.version = api.version || ''" ng-model="api.version" ng-required="true" onchange="generateEndpoint()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="beta">beta</option>
    <option value="v1">v1</option>
  </select>
  <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.version.required">version is required.</span> 
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.endpoint, 'has-success': valid.endpoint}">
  <label for="endpoint">exposure endpoint base path *</label>
  <input type="text" id="endpoint" name="endpoint" class="form-control" placeholder="example: /myapi/v1" ng-model="api.endpoint" ng-required="true">
  <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.endpoint.required">exposure endpoint is required.</span>
</div>
```

**ANGULARJS way**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.api = {};
  $scope.update = function() {
    $scope.api.endpoint = $scope.api.productName + "/" + $scope.api.version;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.productName, 'has-success': valid.productName}">
    <label for="productName">product name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName" class="form-control" placeholder="example: myapi_fr_product " ng-model="api.productName" ng-required="true" ng-change="update()">
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.productName.required">product name is required.</span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.version, 'has-success': valid.version}">
    <label for="version">version *</label>
    <select name="version" id="version" class="form-control" ng-init="api.version = api.version || ''" ng-model="api.version" ng-required="true" ng-change="update()" ;>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="beta">beta</option>
      <option value="v1">v1</option>
    </select>
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.version.required">version is required.</span> 
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': invalid.endpoint, 'has-success': valid.endpoint}">
    <label for="endpoint">exposure endpoint base path *</label>
    <input type="text" id="endpoint" name="endpoint" class="form-control" placeholder="example: /myapi/v1" ng-model="api.endpoint" ng-required="true">
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block" ng-show="help.endpoint.required">exposure endpoint is required.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is working... Yours is not + I just followed the idea of the question using JS. I will update with angularJS way

Comment: Thanksa lot. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Also, I see you are using AngularJS and already have `ng-model` defined. If so, you may call the model directly than using `document.getElementById().value`

```
function generateEndpoint() {
  $scope.api.endpoint = $scope.api.productName + $scope.api.version;

}
```